# Как заставить Spring искать html не в ресурсах?

Tags: java, spring, framework, thymeleaf

Добрый день, дорогие друзья. Работаю со Spring 4 и встал вопрос: до этого все вьюхи помещал в папку resources, но прочитал, что можно поменять путь и размещать вьюхи в другой директории, чтобы при изменении постоянно не перезагружать приложение. Вопрос: как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример из [документации](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html):

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
  <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
  <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
  <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
  <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
</bean>
```

В свойстве `prefix` путь к каталогу, в котором шаблонизатор будет искать вьюхи, а свойство `cacheable` отключает их кэширование, чтобы была возможность вносить изменения без перезапуска приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Или через конфигурационный класс:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setOrder(1);
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    return resolver;
}
}
```